# Facebook: Anonymous users unable to view comments (rate limit exceeded)

Tags: facebook

I often browse Facebook logged out.

Recently, I've noticed that various parts of the interface have been broken completely to the point that it is actively hostile towards anonymous users. As an example:

[image: Screenshot of facebook]

If I click "View 15 more comments" on the public post above, the web app performs a `POST` request to `https://www.facebook.com/api/graphql/` which returns a "HTTP 200" response (clearly not successful) which looks like this:

```
{"errors":[{"message":"Rate limit exceeded","severity":"CRITICAL","code":1675004,"api_error_code":null,"summary":"Query Rate Limit Exceeded","description":"Unknown error","description_raw":"Unknown error","is_silent":true,"is_transient":true,"requires_reauth":false,"allow_user_retry":false,"debug_info":null,"query_path":null,"fbtrace_id":"[redacted]","www_request_id":"[redacted]"}],"extensions":{"is_final":true}}
```

There is no error handling on the frontend whatsoever, the comments just don't get shown.

It doesn't make sense for a rate limit to consistently be exceeded IMO, and I'd not interacted with the app at all today before this happened. I've not seen any other discussion of this problem online though. This isn't a temporary problem, it happens all the time across different browsers.

**Does this behaviour affect everyone who is logged out, or is it somehow just me?** Do I now need an account to continue browsing?

Comment: I don't have a solution for you...but I was searching this exact same issue and found your post. I have noticed this EXACT same thing when using Facebook anonymously. My guess is they limit usage if you don't have an account. Kind of like how Instagram no longer allows anonymous browsing of photos/people.

Comment: Thanks for confirming @Jeff - such a terrible implementation, zero error handling on he UI side!

Comment: I can also add that this seems to affect public posts on pages as well, but only with the new design. Only the first post is loading, the rest are stuck loading indefinitely. I would assume that this is a very conscious choice by Facebook, in order to push people to register with them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would appear to be a deliberate, user-hostile change made to push users to sign up and browse the site authenticated.

As a workaround, the mobile site currently doesn't suffer from this issue.